# Проблема при выводе комментариев

Tags: php, mysql

Что не так? выводятся только родительские комментарии

```
/*
 @comment_id - id комментария
 @parent_id  - id родительского комментария
 @post_id    - id поста таблице posts
 @user_id    - id пользователя оставившего комментарий
 @text       - текст комментария
 @date       - время добавления комментария
*/
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment") or die ('Error #626732');
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        if (!$row['parent_id']){
            echo '<b>'.$row['text'].'</b><br><br><br>';
        }else{
                if ($row['parent_id'] == $row['comment_id']){
                    echo $row['text'];
                }
            }
        }
} else {
    echo 'добавить коммент';
}
```

Выводится только комментарии, где нету дочерних комментов
[image]

Comment: Идем гуглить запрос "рекурсия php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($row['parent_id'] == $row['comment_id']){
    echo $row['text'];
}
```

Это что такое? Сомневаюсь, что в `parent_id` вы храните `comment_id`, следовательно этот блок пропускается. А дальше ничего нет... Т.е. вывода нет, потому и не выводит.

Видно этим условием хотели какую-то логику добавить, может ознакомите с нею? Чтобы знали чем помочь, а сейчас можно только один совет дать - уберите условие, оставьте один вывод.

Все равно условие не выполняется никогда... Т.е. сделайте так:

```
if (!$row['parent_id']){
    echo '<b>'.$row['text'].'</b><br><br><br>';
}else{
    echo $row['text'];
}
```

**UPDATE (ответ на вопрос в комментарии)**:

Первое что необходимо сделать - отделить логику от представления. Т.е. сначала необходимо получить искомые комментарии и только потом отображать их.

Решить задачу можно несколькими способами, приведу только пару из них:

1) Используем рекурсию:

```
function getComments($commentId = 0, $deep = -1) {
    $result = array();
    if ($deep == 0) {
       return $result;
    }
    if ($deep > 0) {
        $deep--;
    }
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE parent_id = " . $commentId);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $result[] = array(
            'text' => $row['text'],
            'comments' => getComments($row['id'], $deep)
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Плюсы:

1. контролируем получаемое число уровней комментариев (т.е. комментариев на комментарии) - параметр $deep. Если равен "-1" - получаем все комментарии, иначе - получаем максимум $deep уровней комментариев.

Недостатки:

1. несколько раз выполняем запрос к БД
2. может не хватить памяти, либо можем получить переполнение стека

2) чтобы убрать возможное переполнение стека можно попробовать заменить рекурсию расчетами в функции, но с ходу не придумал как. Если будет желание - можете попробовать сами.

Сам принцип покажу на примере факториала:

Рекурсия:

```
function fact($n) {
    if ($n > 1) {
        return $n * fact($n - 1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Без рекурсии:

```
function fact($n) {
    $result = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $result = $result * $i;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Из недостатков таким образом убираем переполнение стека, но остальное остается так же как и с рекурсией.

3) Получаем все комментарии, а затем манипулируя полученным массивом получаем нужный результат:

```
function getAllComments() {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE parent_id = " . $commentId);
    $commentList = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $comment = $row;
        $comment['childComments'] = array();
        $commentList[] = $comment;
    }
    return $commentList;
}
function getChildComments(&$commentList, &$currentComment) {
    foreach ($commentList as &$comment) {
        if ($comment['parent_id'] == $currentComment['comment_id']) {
            $currentComment['childComments'][] = &$comment;
        }
    }
}
function getComments($allComments, $parentId) {
    foreach ($commentList as $comment) {
        if ($comment['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            return $comment;
        }
    }
}
$commentList = getAllComments();
foreach ($commentList as &$comment) {
    getChildComments($commentList, $comment);
}
var_dump(getComments($commentList , $parentId = 0));
```

Здесь не нравится то, что делаем всю выборку, а потом гоняем этот огромный массив туда-сюда.

Думаю по коду разберетесь что и где находится. За работу без ошибок не ручаюсь - писал на глаз, возможно где-то что-то упустил, но здесь главное алгоритм. Если поймете что надо делать, то реализуете его уже сами.

Но здесь я привел только примеры получения списка комментариев, а дальше уже легко их можно вывести на экран, т.к. получив один элемент массива (текущий комментарий) мы уже можем легко получить его дочерние комментарии.

Comment: да условие что-то не так сделал, смотрите ваш вариант работает, но сначала выводятся родительские варианты, а потом уже дочерние отдельно, внутри делать ещё один цикл? т.е если у комментария есть дочерний коммент, то делаем цикл и выводим под родительским комментом дочерние? так? что-то не соображу как сделать)

Comment: Смотря что и как хотите. Опишите КАК вы это видите, тогда можно будет сказать ЧТО для этого надо.

Навскидку можно сделать так - выводим сначала родительские комментарии, рядом значок "+". При нажатии на него - подгружаем комменты первого уровня (т.е. комменты именно к нему) и т.д.

Либо делаем рекурсией - но тогда может памяти не хватить если комментов много.

Здесь места для комментов мало отведено, напишите что хотите, тогда дополню свой ответ.

Только дополнить позже смогу, сейчас ухожу уже.

Comment: я добавил картинку в вопрос